# Does Ionic Camera Preview plugin provide a full-quality pic?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, camera

There are 2 ways (that I'm aware of) to capture images/videos from the camera in an ionic app:

- Native camera app
- 'Camera Preview' library

The first option I know will allow users to maximise the potential of the camera (quality, megapixels etc.), but I need the flexibility of adding an overlay (basically I need the flexibility of the second option).

### Question

In the docs I can only see the ability to see a 'quality' argument as part of the '[takePicture](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview)' call, how would a maximum of 100 here compare to the quality of a pic I'd have got from the native app?

I know this is called 'camera preview' but ideally I need it to be the best image quality the camera's capable of capturing (same as the native app).

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take snapshot of the camera preview. The resulting image will be the same size as specified in `startCamera` options. The argument quality defaults to 85 and specifies the quality/compression value: `0=max` compression, `100=max` quality.

```
CameraPreview.takePicture({width:640, height:640, quality: 100}, function(base64PictureData|filePath) {  

  // One simple example is if you are going to use it inside an HTML img src attribute then you would do the following:
  imageSrcData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64PictureData;
  console.log(imageSrcData);
});
```

For More Info Check Documentations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This would take a very different picture compared to the native camera option though. I want to offer my users the ability to take a picture as good as though they are using native, but using the camera preview (I need the custom overlay).

Comment: Yes, Passing `quality:100` will get exact same quality image as native camera.

Comment: I seen the camera preview source though, and it mentions 'upto 2 megapixel'

Comment: If I specify a height and width, I am restricting the picture size - which is not what would happen with the native camera.

Comment: You don't need to pass all options. Just Pass what you required. like you can only pass `quality:100` it will fall back to default with height with 100% quality.

Comment: Ok I will try this out and compare it to the native camera, thank you very much. I am disappointed it can not yet record video on ios, but I hope for that features soon.